# Executing .bat file in FOR loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

#### Edit: Brief Summary

I have number files in a directory, called crash0, crash1 etc. I want to run a `.bat` file for each of this with a command line like:

```
abc.bat crash0 > crash0.txt
```

How can I make another `.bat` file that loops over all the crashXX files calls `abc.bat` once for each one of them?

#### Original Question

Please find my situation below..

I have some files (number may vary each time) in a folder with its name starting with crash. That is crash0, crash1..etc. I want to provide these files as an input to a .bat file (let it be abc.bat) and then navigate the out put a corresponding text file. The command looks like abc.bat crash0 > crash0.txt. I have to do this to all the crash files in the folder. This abc.bat files actually converts the non-readable files to a readable format. So at the end I should have txt files like crash0.txt, crash1.txt.. etc for the corresponding crash files which i provided as the input. Can any one help with a .bat script to run this in cmd?? am new to .bat scripting.. thx in advance

Comment: If you're new at this then it's a good time to start with more current technology. Use VBScript and not a .bat file. VBScript makes thinsg like this very easy.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I thought your question was relevant, but quite hard to read, so I took the liberty to make a summary which I hope is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for %%i in (crash*) do @call abc.bat %%i > %%i.txt`